# Código não esta enviando dados para o banco de dados

Tags: php, query, mysqli

Este primeiro código para cadastro não esta dando certo, ele é igual a outro que esta funcionando que cadastra os usuários, esta dando erro no **$inserenome** e mostra a mensagem **Nao foi possível inserir registro:**, procurei mas não encontro o problema.

> Codigo que esta dando erro

```
<?php

/* substitua as variáveis abaixo pelas que se adequam ao seu caso */
$dbhost = 'localhost'; // endereco do servidor de banco de dados
$dbuser = 'root'; // login do banco de dados
$dbpass = ''; // senha
$dbname = 'delivery'; // nome do banco de dados a ser usado

$conecta = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$seleciona = mysqli_select_db($conecta, $dbname);

$nome           = $_POST ["nome_restaurante"];  
$titulo         = $_POST ["titulo_restaurante"];
$email          = $_POST ["email_restaurante"];
$categoria      = $_POST ["categoria_restaurante"];
$descricaoc     = $_POST ["descricao_curta"];
$descricaol     = $_POST ["descricao_longa"];
$telefone       = $_POST ["telefone_restaurante"];
$site           = $_POST ["site_restaurante"];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO restaurantes (ID, Nome, Titulo, Descricao_curta, Descricao_longa, Logo, Categoria, Telefone, Email, Site) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$nome', '$titulo', '$email', '$categoria', '$descricaoc', '$descricaol', DEFAULT, '$telefone', '$site')";
$inserenome = mysqli_query( $conecta, $sqlinsert );

// inicia a conexao ao servidor de banco de dados
if(! $conecta )
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel conectar: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Conexao realizada!";

// seleciona o banco de dados no qual a tabela vai ser criada
if (! $seleciona)
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel selecionar o banco de dados $dbname");
}
echo "<br />Selecionado o banco de dados $dbname";

// finalmente, cria a tabela 
if(! $inserenome )
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel inserir registro: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Um novo registro foi feito!";
// encerra a conexão
mysqli_close($conecta);

header('Location: index.php')

?>
```

> Codigo que esta funcionando normalmente

```
/* substitua as variáveis abaixo pelas que se adequam ao seu caso */
$dbhost = 'localhost'; // endereco do servidor de banco de dados
$dbuser = 'root'; // login do banco de dados
$dbpass = ''; // senha
$dbname = 'delivery'; // nome do banco de dados a ser usado

$conecta = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$seleciona = mysqli_select_db($conecta, $dbname);

$nome       = $_POST ["nome"];  
$sobrenome  = $_POST ["sobrenome"];
$email      = $_POST ["email"];
$telefone   = $_POST ["telefone"];
$usuario    = $_POST ["usuario"];
$senha      = $_POST ["senha"];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO usuarios (ID, Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Telefone, Usuario, Senha) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$telefone', '$usuario', '$senha')";
$inserenome = mysqli_query( $conecta, $sqlinsert );

// inicia a conexao ao servidor de banco de dados
if(! $conecta )
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel conectar: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Conexao realizada!";

// seleciona o banco de dados no qual a tabela vai ser criada
if (! $seleciona)
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel selecionar o banco de dados $dbname");
}
echo "<br />Selecionado o banco de dados $dbname";

// finalmente, cria a tabela 
if(! $inserenome )
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel inserir registro: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Um novo registro foi feito!";
// encerra a conexão
mysqli_close($conecta);

header('Location: index.php')

?>
```

Tem algo que eu não esteja percebendo?

Comment: Veja se assim retorna algum erro: `$inserenome = mysqli_query( $conecta, $sqlinsert ) or die(mysqli_error($conecta);`

Comment: Já verificou se no html vc mudou o name dos inputs para ser igual aos do $_POST? Dá um echo $sqlinsert; depois do insert e posta.

Comment: Aparentemente até sua mensagem de erro está vindo em branca, provavelmente por estar invocando a função `mysql_error`, enquanto está usando a API `mysqli`. Tente trocá-la por `mysqli_error` que deve aparecer a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @rray , me apareceu isso agora "Field 'telefone' doesn't have a default value" mas deu um echo no $telefone, e ele me mostra o valor certinho

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ele me da erro nos parâmetros ao fazer isso "Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp64\www\delivery\admin\conexao\cadastra.php on line 41"

Comment: `mysqli_error($conecta)`, precisa indicar a conexão com o banco de dados.

Comment: No insert as colunas não batem com valores .... ta `DEFAULT` para telefone ... fora outras coisas.